# How can I use methods defined in this delegate?

Tags: ios, interface

I'm new to iOS development, and I'm playing with an interface trying to understand some concepts. The provided SDK(which is compiled and I can't do anything to it) has the following definitions:

```
@class HRMonitor;
@protocol HRMonitorDelegate
- (void) hrmon: (HRMonitor*) mon heartRateUpdate: (double) hr;
// And others
@end

@interface HRMonitor : NSObject <NSStreamDelegate>{
}

-(id) init: (id) _delegate;
-(void)startup;
```

Does anyone have idea how can I use the `heartRateUpdate` method defined in the protocol `HRMonitorDelegate`? From what I read in the iOS Developer Library, I have to have an interface that conforms to the Delegate like `HRMonitor : NSObject <HRMonitorDelegate>` to call methods in the protocol. But that's not provided in the API.

Or can I use the `init` method? But then how should I pass the `_delegate`?

Comment: Declare your class as conforming to the HRMonitorDelegate (e.g. `MyClass : NSObject <HRMonitorDelegate>`, and implement `- (void) hrmon: (HRMonitor*) mon heartRateUpdate: (double) hr` in your class. Create an instance of `HRMonitor`, (`[[HRMonitor alloc] init]`), and assign yourself as the delegate.

Comment: No, the listed definition is what I got from an compiled SDK. So I can't change the implemenattion.

Comment: Sorry, someone editted my question so it wasn't clear. Now I have added the point that the interface provided is of a compiled SDK.

Comment: Sorry, my comment above should read `[[HRMonitor alloc] init:self]`. That should assign your object as the `HRMonitor`'s delegate, allowing it to receive updates (via `hrmon: heartRateUpdate:`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. conform your interface to the delegate
2. init HRMonitor, passing your interface instance as the _delegate
3. then the  - (void) hrmon: (HRMonitor*) mon heartRateUpdate: (double) hr of you interface will be called
4. make a interface conforms to the delegate, and call the method of it when you need, remember to check the delegate is not nil and response to the method you want to call

   ```
   @interface YourClass : NSObject <HRMonitorDelegate>

   @implementation HRMonitor 

   -(void)someMethod
    {
       HRMonitor monitor = [HRMonitor alloc] init:self];

    }

   - (void) hrmon: (HRMonitor*) mon heartRateUpdate: (double)
   {

   }
   ```

Comment: Sorry, the code is from a .h file of a compiled SDK, so I can't change any part of it.